# docker login fails on a server with no X11 installed

Tags: docker, docker-registry, ubuntu-server

I am trying to deploy a docker configuration with images on a private docker registry.

Now, every time I execute `docker login registry.example.com`, I get the following error message:

> error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`

The only solution I found for non-MacOS users was to run `export $(dbus-launch)` first, but that did not change anything.

I am running Ubuntu Server and tried with both the Ubuntu Docker package and the Docker-CE package.

How can I log in without an X11 session?

Comment: Remove your docker-compose and it should work. It seems like a bug: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6023

Comment: You should consider ChrisWue response as correct.

Answer (score 156):

Looks like this is because it defaults to use the `secretservice` executable which seems to have some sort of X11 dependency for some reason. If you install and configure `pass` docker will use that instead which seems to solve the problem.

In a nutshell (from https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6023)

```
sudo apt install gnupg2 pass 
gpg2 --full-generate-key
```

This generates a you a gpg2 key. After that's done you can list it with

```
gpg2 -k
```

Copy the key id (from the line labelled `[uid]`) and do

```
pass init "whatever key id you have"
```

Now `docker login` should work.

There are a couple of bugs logged on launchpad regarding this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/golang-github-docker-docker-credential-helpers/+bug/1794307

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker-compose/+bug/1796119

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I switched to debian where things work just like they do on my arch dev machine so unfortunately I cannot test your solution

Comment: this solution gave me ``WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/adwised/.docker/config.json.`` on ubuntu18.04

Comment: @MohammadMasoumi then `pass` wasn't installed properly or your docker install can't find it for some reason

Comment: For me (ubuntu 18.04) the instruction "from the line labelled `[uid]`" was incorrect, instead needed to look for the ID in the entry labelled `pub`. (But answer still helpful, this is just an FYI in case others using it encounter the same)

Comment: like @Neo I got "Warning! ... json;" (on debian 10.5) but followed by this advice to fix it : Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Comment: This should be the correct answer, Thanks bro

Comment: Where does this `from the line labelled [uid])` mean?

Comment: I got the `from the line labeled [uid]` meaning, it is from the output of the command `gpg2 --full-generate-key` in the first step.

Comment: Solution working on Ubuntu 18.04 running on WSL 2

Comment: How much time does it take to generate a key?

Comment: I was somehow able to fix the original problem by simply doing `apt install pass`.

Answer (score 119):

This works: `sudo apt remove golang-docker-credential-helpers`

Comment: This works, and allows you to login, but your password will be stored unencrypted. Docker gives this notice: `WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in $HOME/.docker/config.json.`

Comment: This `docker login` failure is apparently [a known issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6023) which is attributed to the `golang-docker-credential-helpers` Ubuntu package. This answer does work to allow you to `docker login` without a GUI, but as @tmuecksch mentioned, afterwards you will have to reinstall `docker-compose` (and the `golang...` package, if you want it). As mentinoed by @Azeirah, I did get a warning stating `my password will be stored unencrypted in ...`, but it was not actually stored anywhere that I could find.

Comment: Fixed the problem but also uninstalled `docker-compose`.

Comment: The real question is, how to get the old behaviour (storing unencrypted in xyz) without **uninstalling** anything.

Comment: mmmm, I don't like to store my passwords unencrypted !

Comment: Yep, this worked! And when vim /root/.docker/config.json, my token is not there, but a long not identified string for "auth".

Comment: @RicHincapie : try decoding it with base64 :-) `grep '"auth"' /root/.docker/config.json   | cut -d'"' -f4 | base64 -d`

Comment: Lol, sure. Hadn't realized by then. Thanks @Edheldil

Comment: huge thanks, that was a lifesaver

Answer (score 41):

You can remove the offending package `golang-docker-credential-helpers` without removing all of `docker-compose`.

The following worked for me on a server without X11 installed:

```
dpkg -r --ignore-depends=golang-docker-credential-helpers golang-docker-credential-helpers
```

and then

```
echo 'foo' | docker login mydockerrepo.com -u dockeruser --password-stdin
```

Source:

bug reported in debian:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=910823#39
bug reported on ubuntu:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker-compose/+bug/1796119

Comment: That work for me, but is there a risk that the package gets reinstalled automatically in case of a future update?

Comment: work for me at `Version:          23.0.2`

Answer (score 28):

`secretservice` requires a GUI. You can use `pass` without a GUI.

Unfortunately, Docker's [documentation on how to configure Docker Credential Helpers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store) is quite lacking. Here's a comprehensive guide how to configure `pass` with Docker (tested with Ubuntu 18.04):

#### 1. Install the Docker Credential Helper for `pass`

- Find the url for the latest version of `docker-credential-pass` from https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases . For example:

```sh
# substitute with the latest version
url=https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases/download/v0.6.2/docker-credential-pass-v0.6.2-amd64.tar.gz

# download and untar the binary
wget $url
tar -xzvf $(basename $url)

# move the binary to a dir in your $PATH
sudo mv docker-credential-pass /usr/local/bin

# verify it works
docker-credential-pass list
```

#### 2. Install and configure `pass`

```sh
apt install pass

# create a gpg2 key
gpg2 --gen-key
# if you have issues with lack of entropy, "apt install haveged" and try again

# create the password store using the gpg user id above
pass init $gpg_id
```

#### 3. docker login

```sh
docker login

# You should not see any credentials stored in "auths" section.
# "credsStore": "pass" should have been automatically added.
# If the value is "secretservice", replace it with "pass".
cat ~/.docker/config.json

# verify credentials stored in `pass` store now
pass
```

Answer (score 17):

There is a much easier answer than the ones already posted, which I found in a comment on https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/105.

The solution is to rename docker-credential-secretservice out of the way 
e.g: `mv /usr/bin/docker-credential-secretservice /usr/bin/docker-credential-secretservice.broken`

Once you do this, docker login works regardless of whether or not docker-compose is installed. No other package additions or removals are necessary.

Comment: tried that but now I get `Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-secretservice": executable file not found in $PATH, out: ```

Comment: Worked for me using aws cli. I'm using an EC2 server launched from an image with docker installed. Each time I start a new instance I have to do this or else I can't authenticate with aws cli. Thanks

Comment: Worked for  me on a gcp instance

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!

Comment: Thank you!  In my script I move it (as you suggested), do my docker login, then move it back.

Answer (score 3):

I've resolved this issue by uninstalling `docker-compose` which was installed from Ubuntu repo and installing `docker-compose` by official instruction at https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose

Comment: the existence of a package manager is a huge advantage of linux over other operating systems. you usually don't want to install software without your distribution's package manager's awareness, for example by simply downloading software and copy it to `/usr/bin` or similar. the very obvious reason that you can update all software with just one command, another one is that you can have dependencies on other packages.

Comment: I resolved this issue by removing ubuntu from my system and used a system capable of running docker (I'm using debian for stable and fedora for staging).

Comment: @msrd0 lack of software isolation introduced by package system is a huge disadvantage of linux and the reason why such "hacks" like docker even exists. Back to the subject: this issue is introduced in Ubuntu package, wipe out Ubuntu is a not solution, so what workaround you are suggesting?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. Some distributions like fedora ship with selinux, but can't replace isolation done by docker. I asked this question hoping to get a workaround that is acceptable (like changing a config file or similar, not "disabling" the package manager), but haven't found one, so removing ubuntu was the only possible outcome for me

Comment: And the nice thing about docker is that you can have a `docker-compose.yml`, copy that to a different operating system with docker installed, copy the directory with all your docker volumes, and you won't notice any difference to your previous operating system.

Comment: it is good as a quick fix for those who not concern about updating it time to time

Answer (score 3):

What helped me on Ubuntu 18.04 was:

1. Following the steps in @oberstet 's post and uninstalling the golang helper
2. Performing a login after the helper uninstall
3. Reinstalling docker via `sudo apt-get install docker`
4. Logging back in via `sudo docker login`