# How to force 'docker login' command to ignore existing credentials helper?

Tags: docker, credentials

I have a system where I'm trying to run the `docker login`command, it is a headless linux system, but unfortunately only the [Docker Credentials Helper](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store) docker-credential-secretservice is installed.

This means that I get the following error:

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`
```

It makes sense that I get this as:

> By default, Docker looks for the native binary on each of the
>   platforms, i.e. “osxkeychain” on macOS, “wincred” on windows, and
>   “pass” on Linux. **A special case is that on Linux, Docker will fall
>   back to the “secretservice” binary if it cannot find the “pass”
>   binary**. If none of these binaries are present, it stores the
>   credentials (i.e. password) in base64 encoding in the config files
>   described above.

And since `secretservice` helper uses a GUI credentials store it tries to open a window, which it can't on the headless system.

I've no control over the system, so I can't remove the `/usr/bin/docker-credential-secretservice` file to force `docker login` to fall back to the config file rather than using the `secretservice` helper.

What I can do is create and list files in my user's home folder. I've tried to run the command as such:

```
docker --config ./docker login -u <user-name> -p <password> <repository>
```

I was under the impression that the login command would then create a `config.json` in the ./docker (I've noticed `docker login` will create the folder if it doesn't exist). This works on a system that doesn't have any helpers installed, but not on the system in question.

I've also tried to create a `~/.docker/config.json` with something like:

```
echo '{"credStore":""}' > ~/.docker/config.json
```

Hoping that `docker login` would get the hint not to use any helpers for the credential store.

Is there a way for a non-admin to force `docker login` to fall back to:

> stores the credentials (i.e. password) in base64 encoding in the config files described above.
>   Without deleting the credentials helper?

(as a side note, I'll of course ask to have the `/usr/bin/docker-credential-secretservice` removed but, in case it's not possible or for future reference, are there any alternative solutions?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, Docker (as of 18.06) first looks for the `docker-credential-*` binaries, and if it finds any of them, it will automatically overwrite the `"credsStore"` value in `~/.docker/config.json`.

Your only workaround would be to install `docker-credential-pass` in your home directory so that Docker will use that instead of `docker-credential-secretservice`. `docker-credential-pass` does not require a GUI.

Steps to install `docker-credential-pass`:

[docker login fails on a server with no X11 installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222996/docker-login-fails-on-a-server-with-no-x11-installed/56962332#56962332)

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers mentions `pass`, but doesn't explain what `pass` is.  `pass` is the Standard Unix Password Manager

Comment: On Windows, if it doesn't find the default `docker-credential-winpass` helper it'll just fail with an error message, it doesn't fall back to anything else, so you can't just remove the default helper, you have to define a replacement.

Answer (score 20):

Logging out the current user, before logging in with a different user name worked for me. Logging out removed the saved docker credentials.

```
docker logout <reponame> 
docker login <reponame>
```

Answer (score 15):

To avoid using a `credsStore` and to store a plaintext auth token in your docker config (e.g. `~/.docker/config.json`), delete the `"credsStore"` key from your docker config file and rerun `docker login`.

When you run `docker login`, it will give a warning but will save the auth token into the file.

```sh
$ docker login
Username: someuser
Password:
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in ~/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

The resulting docker config file should look like this:

```json
{
        "auths": {
                "your.docker.registry": {
                        "auth": "dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQK="
                }
        }
}
```

The `auth` token is simply a base64 encoded string of the form `username:password`.

This worked for Docker Engine versions 19 and 20.

Comment: if you can, just delete or rename /usr/bin/docker-credential-pass and remove entry in ~/.docker/config.json. use of `pass` with docker is WAY TOO COMPLICATED and HUGELY ERROR PRONE.

Comment: Deleting the `credStore` field worked for me. On the login following deleting credstore, it showed the warning and saved the auth token as a base64 in the config. Just a suggestion: using the `docker --config` option to use config in some place other than your actual `~/.docker/config.json` makes it easier to perform these messy operations without worrying about screwing up your actual config.

Answer (score 3):

I've looked through the code and there appears to be no way to generally disable the use of credential helpers. **But** you *can* skip the code path on a per-registry basis.

https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/25eee83d6b8c475548254b2decc9c8e0490d229c/cli/config/configfile/file.go#L308 will look up the helper to use (just the suffix after `docker-credential-`) in `credHelpers` from the registry host name. If it is `""` it will use the normal unencrypted file store. As far as I can tell, this is undocumented and likely unintended behavior.

With that, in order to bypass the credential helpers for a specific registry, do

```sh
mkdir ./docker
echo "{\"credHelpers\": {\"$REGISTRY_HOST\": \"\"}}" > ./docker/config.json
docker --config ./docker login -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD $REGISTRY_HOST
```

I believe the cause why `{"credsStore":""}` isn't working is the `omitempty` serialization tag on that field. Setting it to empty is the same as not setting it.

Comment: WFM, Docker desktop 4.17.  I added this to my config.json: `"credHelpers": { "artifactory.example.com": "", "docker.io": "" }`

Answer (score 2):

Simply rename `~/.docker/config.json` to something different, or remove it if you won't need it anymore.

`mv ~/.docker/config.json ~/.docker/backup-config.json`

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the question, but maybe to the problem:

We can launch dbus ourselves then unlock/lock/query the keyring from the cli.

These are the bash functions I use:

```
function unlock-keyring () {
export $(dbus-launch)
read -rsp "Password: " pass
export $(echo -n "$pass" | gnome-keyring-daemon --unlock)
unset pass
}

function lock-keyring () {
dbus-send --dest=org.gnome.keyring --print-reply /org/freedesktop/secrets org.freedesktop.Secret.Service.LockService
}

function query-keyring-locked () {
busctl --user get-property org.freedesktop.secrets /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection Locked
}
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473528/how-do-you-enable-the-secret-tool-command-backed-by-gnome-keyring-libsecret-an

https://superuser.com/questions/700826/how-to-lock-a-unlocked-gnome-keyring

https://superuser.com/questions/1618970/query-status-of-gnome-keyring

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602313/unlock-gnome-keyring-daemon-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

You can just ignore all the output by sending everything to `/dev/null` like:

`echo $TOKEN|docker login -u=user --password-stdin myregistry.com > /dev/null 2>&1`
where `$TOKEN` will be your previously exported token or password.

This will be useful as well with CI's when using some automation

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR answer: make sure the help isn't on the `PATH`, e.g:

```
PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -e 's_:/usr/bin__') /usr/bin/docker login ...
```

---

I've got the same problem with docker `24.0.6` on Linux, but my system is picking up `docker-credential-pass`. One user on my system uses that, so I can't remove it. I just need other users to be able to use the base64-in-config method.

My solution is to modify the `PATH` just for the docker command.

> Docker looks for the native binary on each of the platforms...

...means the PATH is searched, so I

1. find the path of `docker`

```bash
$ which docker
/usr/bin/docker
```

2. find the path of the helper:

```bash
$ which docker-credential-pass
/usr/bin/docker-credential-pass
```

3. write a command that:

- calls the `docker` binary with the fully qualified path, so that means using `/usr/bin/docker` instead of just `docker`
- modifies the `PATH` to remove the dir that contains the helper (just happens to be the same dir as the docker binary, which is why we have to fully qualify that). There are many ways to do it based on your shell and how your `PATH` is arranged.

In my `PATH`, `/usr/bin` is at the end, so I use
`sed` to replace that string fragment with nothing. The That command looks like:

```
PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -e 's_:/usr/bin__') /usr/bin/docker login ...
```

Answer (score -1):

This will do the trick just to avoid the nag:

```
echo ${DOCKERPW} | docker login -u ${DOCKERUSER} --password-stdin 2> /dev/null
```