# Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: no credentials server URL, out: `no credentials server URL` while login into docker

Tags: docker, dockerhub

While login into docker account through I'm getting below error. The login is working fine in browser.

`docker login`

Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.

`Username: ********`

`Password:`

After putting my password I'm getting below error in the terminal

> Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: no credentials server URL, out: `no credentials server URL`

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Check if your docker daemon is running

Comment: @Wander3r It was not running though. I simply renamed docker-credential-osxkeychain and login worked after that.

Comment: @Wander3r , Your tip worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Late to the party but I solved this issue:

### TL;DR

run `sudo apt install -y gnupg2 pass` and try again

---

### Issue

When running `docker logout` I got the following error message:

```
error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

Which led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222996/docker-login-fails-on-a-server-with-no-x11-installed) StackOverflow post

---

### Solution

The solution is to install some X11 tools and try again logging in:

```
sudo apt install -y gnupg2 pass
docker logout
docker login
```

Comment: Confirming that this solves a described issue on Ubuntu server images of AWS EC2 machines.

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove `docker-credential-osxkeychain` file present in `/usr/local/bin/` directory.

I renamed that file and it worked.

`mv docker-credential-osxkeychain docker-credential-osxkeychain-backup`

```
docker login
```

Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.

`Username: ******`

`Password:`

> WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /Users/******/.docker/config.json.
>   Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
>   https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
>
> Login Succeeded

Comment: I do not have this file, so this solution don't work for me

Comment: For me, this solution worked just fine. And, the password is stored encrypted in `config.json`

Comment: That file will only exist if you've installed it on MacOS, you won't have it on Linux. Another note, the password is not "encrypted" in `config.json` - it is base64-encoded.

Comment: I'm on MacOs with this file existing, but this didn't help...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using ubuntu 22.04.1, to solve it I had to run:

```
sudo apt install golang-docker-credential-helpers
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case ( Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64  ) I followed these steps,

`gpg --generate-key`

then

`pass init <generated gpg-id public key>`

after that,

`docker login`

make sure you have a docker hub account.
for more details, see this [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/get-started/#credentials-management-for-linux-users).